# How to delete a row inside trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

Is there any way to delete a row inside trigger (on the table which fired the trigger) in MariaDB/MySQL?

I know it's possible to do so in postgres.

Here is the SQL I've tried.

```
TRIGGER trigger AFTER INSERT ON table FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DELETE FROM table
WHERE expire_at <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Code: 1442. Can't update table 'cluster_events' in stored
>   function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
>   this stored function/trigger.

Is it possible to solve this some other way?

Comment: 'Is there any way to delete a row inside trigger in MariaDB/MySQL' - not if its a delete on the table which fired the trigger.

Comment: you can use sp from trigger to do the delete operation

Comment: Well, I've tried to make a procedure that do the delete operation on the table and called it inside trigger but it gives just same result.

Comment: @james no you can't mysql won't allow it nor will it allow it if a function containing the delete is called.

Comment: 'Is it possible to solve this some other way?' - would you really want to delete for each row? You might consider including the insert and delete in a transaction.

Comment: Are you expecting to delete the row that caused the Trigger or some other row(s)?  The Delete has nothing to do with the thing causing the Trigger, so _logically_ they don't belong together.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to periodically purge 'old' data, use an `EVENT`.

Be sure to turn on the Event Scheduler.